2000s animated series in which a guy would travel between multiple locations through a magical waterfall
I have been searching for an animated show where a guy would travel from one place to another through a magical waterfall.
Anyone remember the name of the cartoon?

Was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)? And what sort of locations would the guy travel to?

Ethelbert the Tiger (1996) had this schtick. The titular heroes would go through a magic waterfall to a new adventure each episode.

